# What's the means of mongodb connect to multiple servers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm a novice at MongoDB development.

I want know what's the means that in MongoDB-Csharp-Driver if Connection String written like 
`"mongodb://server1,server2:27017,server2:27018"`

Does that means the Client App can send a operation to several servers at same time ? or others ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your English is a bit confusing but I think the answer is no.

Multiple server definition within the connection string is either a list of mongos instances or a seedlist for a replica set.